# Firebase Firestore: Issues with combining exclusion query and sorting

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is what I am trying to do with my Firestore database:

1. Query from 'posts' collection, which contains the following fields: 'userid', 'time', and 'listid'.
2. Query the latest 4 documents that includes the target userid variable, and whose 'listid' values are not equal to the target listid variable.

Here is my initial query, which came up with the error message: 'inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same'

```
 return db.collection('posts').where('userid','==',targetuserid)
     .where('listid','!=',targetlistid)
     .orderBy("time","desc")
     limit(4).get()
```

Here is my revised query, which doesn't trigger the error message anymore.

```
 return db.collection('posts').where('userid','==',targetuserid)
     .where('listid','!=',targetlistid)
     .orderBy("listid").orderBy("time","desc")
     limit(4).get()
```

However, here is the issue with the revised query: Rather than returning the actual latest documents, the query sorts first based on 'listid' fields, which are randomly generated, and so returns random documents that were generated long ago.

Is there a workaround in Firestore query methods that can help me do what I want to do, or is it not possible in Firestore yet and I have to start thinking about alternatives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when using a `!=` clause, there are *far more* documents *included* in the query than *excluded* - in this case, it is likely much much easier to *not* include the `!=` clause (which is an inequality), and thus allow your `orderBy()` and `.limit()` to work - and you can remove/ignore the undesired documents in the client code.  Getting a couple "extra" documents  in the read (ie the `!=` ones) is much less expensive than having to read *all* the documents other than the few you wanted to exclude.

The issues with the `!=` clause and `orderBy()` has become an extremely common question here on StackOverflow - to be honest, I haven't yet seen a situation where it actually has been useful...